# Filling out forms with urllib2 with pre-determined entries

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm having trouble with the urllib2 module.

I would like to autofill a form. Most tutorials and examples detail how one might do this when you have a box in which you enter your query/entry. However, the form I wish to fill out has a sort of dropdown menu. I was wondering if there was documentation available on filling out forms with dropdown menus.

To be clear, the relevant code from the page is:

```
<label for="Thing1"><span class="hiddenLabel">Thing1</span></label>
<div id="ID1" class="Class1" style="display: none;">                        
  <select id="ID2" name="virusASegments" class="deSelectEvent" multiple="multiple" size="12">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="option1">1 option1</option>
    <option value="option2">2 option2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="_name" value="1"/>
</div>
```

I would like to define `Thing1` as "option2"

Comment: Please add some python code to support your question

Comment: You use the `name` from the select tag and then the `value` from the relevant option.

Answer (score -1):

```
  select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ID2'))
  select.select_by_value('option2')
```